# Generate jasper report using singe java bean

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

i have requirement to create order declaration report, i am using jasper studio to create the jasper template. in that template i have order id, customer details and his address, with these details i have to create a report.

i have below jasper report code

```
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("src/main/resource/orderDeclarationForm.jrxml");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("src/main/resource/orderDeclarationForm.jasper", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new JRTableModelDataSource(getTableModelData()));
    // JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile("resource/orderDeclarationForm.jrprint");
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "src/main/resource/orderDeclarationForm.pdf");
```

but instead of `JRTableModelDataSource` i have to pass java bean class so the jasper engine has to take the data from one single java bean, i have gone through `javabean as datasource` where it takes list of beans, but my requirement is only one bean which has order details. please advice me on this

Comment: Firsty, it should be "src/main/resources" not "src/main/resource". Secondly, you should never reference "src/main/resources" in java code. This folder should be added to the runtime classath and you should simply reference "orderDeclarationForm.jrxml"

Comment: @LanceJava thx for pointing out, will fix those

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one instance of a bean to be passed to **JasperFillManager.fillReport** method, then it makes sense to pass them as parameters as long as their count is feasible (in your case its only 3).

```
    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    params.put("orderId", xxx);
    params.put("customerDetails", xxx);
    params.put("address", xxx);
```

Afterwards, pass this params Map object:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("src/main/resource/orderDeclarationForm.jasper", params, new JRTableModelDataSource(getTableModelData()));
```

Please check [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-parameters) link for more info on how to read Parameters from within your .jrxml file.

Thanks.